# Android IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity. When launching a new activity

Tags: android

I'm trying to launch another activity from a button click. I've seen this happen on another question where there were more than one intent filter attributes in the manifest file.

This is the Activity I'm trying to launch the second activity from

```
    public class MainMenu extends Activity{

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_menu);
        }

        public void launchMovie(View view){
            startActivity(new Intent(this, Movies.class));
        }

    }
```

The corresponding layout file

```
<HorizontalScrollView

    android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_alacarte"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:onClick="launchMovie"
            android:text="MOVIES"/>
```

This is my manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.iphonik.chameleon">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
        <activity android:name=".MainMenu">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Put your activity in `manifest.xml`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your Movies activity in your manifest:

```
<activity android:name=".Movies" />
```

Like this:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
    <activity android:name=".MainMenu">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Movies" />

</application>
```